# How do I find the index of an object from a list in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, list, indexing, find

Say I have a list, and I have an object. How do I find the index of that object in the list?

Comment: ListBox or ListView or List<>?

Comment: Assuming that the list is a Generics.List(of ...) then this question is unfortunately ambiguous, or at least it is treated that way by MS.  For some years I have been using IndexOf and Contains without thinking about it because I thought they did what their names imply.  But they don't search for the object but for one that satisfies the Equals function.  This means that if you have overriden Equals then IndexOf might return a value even if the object is not present because an object in the list returns True for obj.Equals(target).  This is never what I want unless the objects are immutable

Comment: Related (***not*** duplicate): For the simpler case of checking for **existence** and of a simple `List(Of String)`), see: *[Check if a list of strings contains a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732563)*

Answer (score 41):

You can use [FindIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca.aspx) to find the index of an object in a generic List:
This is the most flexible method to get the index of an object.

```
 Dim list As New List(Of Object)
 Const myApple = "Apple111"
 For i = 0 To 1000
     List.Add("Apple" & i)
 Next
 Dim indexOfMyApple = list.FindIndex(Function(apple) myApple.Equals(apple))
```

But the [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17.aspx) method is even simplier and more straightforward if you only want to find an  object in a List by the [DefaultEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx):

```
Dim indexOfMyApple = list.IndexOf(myApple)
```

You can use `IndexOf` also if you don't know what type it is, .NET will use [Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.equals%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to determine if two objects are equal(should be overridden to not only compare references).

Comment: what if I don't know what is in the object. I have only the reference but no idea about the contents of the objects.?