# Check if a list of strings contains a value

Tags: .net, vb.net, list

I have:

```
Public lsAuthors As List(Of String)
```

I want to add values to this list, but before adding I need to check if the exact value is already in it. How do I figure that out?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use [`List.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
If Not lsAuthors.Contains(newAuthor) Then
    lsAuthors.Add(newAuthor)
End If
```

or with LINQs `Enumerable.Any`:

```
Dim authors = From author In lsAuthors Where author = newAuthor
If Not authors.Any() Then
    lsAuthors.Add(newAuthor)
End If
```

You could also use an efficient [`HashSet(Of String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of the list which doesn't allow duplicates and returns `False` in [`HashSet.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) if the string was already in the set.

```
 Dim isNew As Boolean = lsAuthors.Add(newAuthor)  ' presuming lsAuthors is a HashSet(Of String)
```

Answer (score 11):

The generic List has a method called [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx) that returns true if the default comparer for the choosen type finds an element matching the searching criteria.

For a List(Of String) this is the normal string comparison, so your code could be

```
Dim newAuthor = "Edgar Allan Poe"
if Not lsAuthors.Contains(newAuthor) Then
    lsAuthors.Add(newAuthor)
End If
```

As a side note, the default comparison for strings considers two strings different if they don't have the same case. So if your try to add an author named "edgar allan poe" and you already have added one with the name "Edgar Allan Poe" the barebone Contains fails to notice that they are the same.
If you have to manage this situation then you need

```
....
if Not lsAuthors.Contains(newAuthor, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) Then
    .....
```

Comment: I tried that before, I get an object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @Medise: then initialize the list. `Public lsAuthors As New List(Of String)`

Answer (score 2):

To check whether an element is present in a list you can use the [list.Contains()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx) method. If you are using a button click to populate the list of strings then see the code:

```
Public lsAuthors As List(Of String) = New List(Of String) ' Declaration of an empty list of strings

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click ' A button click populates the list
    If Not lsAuthors.Contains(TextBox2.Text) Then ' Check whether the list contains the item that to be inserted
        lsAuthors.Add(TextBox2.Text) ' If not then add the item to the list
    Else
        MsgBox("The item Already exist in the list") ' Else alert the user that item already exist
    End If
End Sub
```

**Note: Line by line explanation is given as comments**

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of matching items of your condition like this:

```
Dim lsAuthors As List(Of String)

Dim ResultData As String = lsAuthors.FirstOrDefault(Function(name) name.ToUpper().Contains(SearchFor.ToUpper()))
If ResultData <> String.Empty Then
    ' Item found
Else
    ' Item Not found
End If
```