# Check if a string list contains an item

Tags: c#, string

I have a string list like;

```
public static readonly List<string> myList = new List<string>
{
    "123",
    "456",
    "789"
};
```

And I have a method, let's say MethodX(string). MethodX(string) is looking for and compares entered string in another string list that comes from API. It returns true if an entered string matches any string from the list.

Now what I'm doing is;

```
var y = myList;
foreach (var x in y)
{
    var asd = me.MethodX(x);
    if (asd == true)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

I want every member of the string list to be entered MethodX() and check if it's true. But currently it only tries "123" as the first member of myList.

How can I make it happen?

Comment: Wouldn't something like myList.Any(str => MethodX(str)) work? 
In your example code, you're using MethodX awkwardly, passing a list and not a string there. Does it accept a string or a list of strings?

Comment: @WhaleSong it only accepts string but since it's a list I'm using it inside of foreach. So it should be looking for each member, I guess?

Comment: It looks right then!

Comment: "But currently it only tries "123" as the first member of myList". No, it doesn't. The code you posted will call `MethodX` for every item in `myList`. So what makes you think it doesn't?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a list of string contains a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732563/check-if-a-list-of-string-contains-a-value)

Answer (score 0):

```
bool MethodX(this List<string>,string x)
{
   return this.Any(s=>s==x);
}
```