# Comparing String to List of String in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

Example: How do I compare one string out of a list against   my desired string? Please help!

```
Dim myString As String                 

Dim myList As List(Of String)
```

Let's say myString Returns Bob   and myList Returns  (Bob, Mary, Sally, Joe)

I Need to do the following:

```
If(myString = myList) Then
      //Do some code
End If
```

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732563/check-if-a-list-of-strings-contains-a-value

Comment: A string is not equal to a list of string. However a list of strings can contain a particular string. Is that what you wanted to check for? Did you look at the methods available on the List class?

Comment: Consider using a HashSet instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to compare a string out of a list of strings to your desired string, you must know where in the list the string is that you want to compare with.

```vb
Dim myString As String
Dim myList as List(Of String)

'this will compare your string to the first string in the list of strings
If myString = myList(0) Then
    'do something
End If
```

If you would like to see if any of the strings in the list are equal to your string, do this

```vb
For i = 0 to myList.Count - 1
    If myString = myList(i) Then
        'do something
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test whether the list contains "Bob" you can use the Contains Method:

```
    Dim myList As New List(Of String)
    myList.Add("Bob")
    If(myList.Contains("Bob")) Then
        Console.WriteLine("Yes, it is in the list")
    End If
```